How to Set Conditional State Transitions Based on Boolean Field in Azure DevOps WITD XML
I am customizing the workflow for a work item type in Azure DevOps and need to set state transitions based on the value of a boolean custom field (Abc.CustomField). Specifically:
If Abc.CustomField is true, the next state available in state dropdown should be "Done".
If Abc.CustomField is false, the next state available in state dropdown should be "Terminated".

Can you explain what it WITD XML? Do you mean that you are using XML Process?

Hi @Kevin , Yes I am using XML Process.

Thanks for your feedback. Please check the answer below and we can use conditional-based values and rules in XML Process to achieve it.

Based on your description, you need to set the state value based on the custom work item field value.
To meet your requirement, you can define the conditional-based values and rules in XML Process.
Here is an example: We can use WHEN to set the condition based on the  Abc.CustomField
<FIELD name="State" refname="System.State" type="String" reportable="dimension" />
       <ALLOWEDVALUES>  
           <LISTITEM value="New" />  
           <LISTITEM value="Active" />  
           <LISTITEM value="Done" /> 
           <LISTITEM value="Terminated" />  
       </ALLOWEDVALUES>   
       <WHEN field="Abc.CustomField" value="true">  
           <ALLOWEDVALUES>  
               <LISTITEM value="Done" />                
           </ALLOWEDVALUES>  
       </WHEN>  
       <WHEN field="Abc.CustomField" value="false">  
           <ALLOWEDVALUES>  
               <LISTITEM value="Terminated" />                
           </ALLOWEDVALUES>  
       </WHEN>  

</FIELD>  

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Assign conditional-based values and rules
If you are using inherited processes, you can use the Work Item Rule to achieve the same feature.
